# Access R output with subsetting

Tags: r, subset

I do have the output of a function which looks like this

```
function(i,var1,list1)->h
```

and then the output

```
   value
2.8763
```

There is a line break in the output and I only need the number bit of the result but not the string. Hence, I tried to use h[1] but this is

```
value
2.87..
```

and length(h) is also equal 1. Is there any way to access only the number in this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you **are** accessing only the value and the name you see is the name of the element in a vector you return. you can get rid of those names / attributes like this:

```
> v <- c("a" = 1, "b" = 2)
> v
a b 
1 2 
> attributes(v) <- NULL
> v
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: or even shorter `unname(v)`